# Can I cut up a 15x20cm Novoflex Graycard without ruining its properties?

Tags: white-balance, canon-60d, gray-card, novoflex

I purchased a graycard, specifically a Novoflex 15x20cm (~ 6x8") card that is white on one side and 18%? gray on the other side.

However, it's a bit too large to comfortably fit into jacket pocket or my photo bag, so I'm wondering...

If I cut the card in half, or even smaller, will I be ruining any of its properties?

I'm thinking more about the physical properties than it's photo properties. For instance, I'm wondering if the outer edge of the full card has been treated so that the glue that holds the two cards (I'm assuming they have glued two cards of different colors together) isn't exposed, but if I start cutting it up, I will be exposing glue that can react to humidity, etc.

I was thinking of cutting the card first in half, to get 2  pieces, 3x4", and then cutting one of those in half again, to get 3 pieces, 1 3x4" piece, and 2 1.5x2" pieces, they would probably fit my usage better.

And about the photo properties of the card, will reducing their size reduce their usefulness. For instance, does a my camera, a Canon EOS 60D, require a large area to properly measure the white balance or whatnot, so that if I reduce the cards size too much, I reduce the distance I can be from the card when taking a picture of it?

Basically, I would like advice on whether cutting up the card will at all make it unusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a good reason why it would be a problem to cut it up.

So long as the grey is clearly visible on the test image you take then that's all you need.  I'd tend to do the colour correction on post but that's a matter of workflow.  Size wise even your smallest size is a larger grey area than the likes of the [Datacolor SpyderCube](http://spyder.datacolor.com/en/portfolio-view/spydercube-video/).

Comment: OK, I took a chance and cut it up into 3 smaller pieces like I planned, much more userfriendly for me now :) I'm going to file down the corners to make them more smooth, but otherwise it looks very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I took a chance based on the answer here, and some tips I found on the internet as well, and cut it up as planned, end result:

[image: Novoflex Gray card cut into smaller pieces]